# List to dataframe, each element in list in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ho everyone,

I want to create a dataframe from list, where each element from a list is a column.
Example:

```
    Col
0   A_1
1   A_2
2   A_1
3   B_3
4   B_2
```

I want to have a dataframe like this

```
Col1 . col2 
0   A .  1  
1   A .  2
2   B .  3
3   B .  2
```

....

split by the '_' and make two columns and remove the duplicate

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df[['Col1','Col2']]=df.pop('Col').str.split("_",expand=True)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df)

  Col1 Col2
0    A    1
1    A    2
3    B    3
4    B    2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had this error ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: @noaai possible that you have 2 underscores in some data?

Answer (score 1):

Using `extract`

```
yourdf=df.drop_duplicates().Col.str.extract(r'(?P<col1>[AB])_(?P<col2>\d)')
yourdf
Out[16]: 
  col1 col2
0    A    1
1    A    2
3    B    3
4    B    2
```